# What is going on with Russell's "beauty cold and austere" of mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, bertrand-russell

I admit that this is an idle question, but I wondered why it is that mathematics appears "**beautiful cold and austere**" to those who are particularly gifted at it. The full quite from wikipedia on this is, from Russell:

> Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only truth, but supreme
>   beauty — a beauty cold and austere, like that of sculpture, without
>   appeal to any part of our weaker nature, without the gorgeous
>   trappings of painting or music, yet sublimely pure, and capable of a
>   stern perfection such as only the greatest art can show. The true
>   spirit of delight, the exaltation, the sense of being more than Man,
>   which is the touchstone of the highest excellence, is to be found in
>   mathematics as surely as poetry.

I can relate to ideas, from wikipedia, of "elegance", and "depth", which may be why I like chat about philosophy. And, applied mathematics can be pleasing, I agree.

But it's those terms "austere" and "cold" which I cannot relate to. Is that Betrand's philosophy, or does it apply to some aspect of maths -- that is only available to some few?

Comment: a bit "what is a star" but yea

Comment: oh come on what's wrong with this question -- please?

Comment: Someone who took several hundred pages to prove that 1 + 1 = 2 might possibly be drawn to the cold and austere. Russell's view says more about Russell than about math. At least that's a point of view that might be argued. What is different about math versus music is that you can only appreciate math to the degree that you've spent years learning to understand it; whereas music and art can be appreciated by anyone. But that doesn't make math's beauty cold and austere; only difficult to access. Once one accesses it, it can be warm and fuzzy. Fuzzy sets for example :-)

Comment: @user4894 appreciate the comment, thanks

Comment: @user4894 "you can only appreciate math to the degree that you've spent years learning to understand it" that is not true at all. There are hundreds of youtube channels that explain complicated math assuming little background knowledge solely for the purposes of entertainment. Many of those channels have huge audiences that appreciate the beauty of the math even without a rigorous understanding. And music is not appreciated by all people without musical backgrounds. John Cage's *4'33"* is laughed at by most non musicians and Ornette Coleman's *The Shape of Jazz to Come* is called noise.

Comment: Many people can see the beauty of Eulers identity without spending any time learning complex analysis, it just takes a short time to explain the constants that aren't familiar to everyone. Many people are infatuated with Gödels incompleteness theorems, especially people who have absolutely no idea what they actually say and try to use them to prove things that they have no relation to! Complicated, sophisticated pieces of art and music are often times called pointless by people without the artistic training to appreciate them. Mathematical beauty can be very accessible, thats why it transcends

Comment: It is simply the point of view of Russell, based on a difference between "forms of beauty" : that of pictorial art and music, more linked to "our weaker nature" (what ?), than sculpture and poetry:more "high". This distinction about "forms of beauty" seems to me quite unconvincing, but if we can speak of *beauty* for math it is clearly something more "intellectual" and contemplative.

Comment: Maybe relevant: *The Phenomenology of Mathematical Beauty*, in [Gian-Carlo Rota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian-Carlo_Rota) & Fabrizio Palombi, [Indiscrete thoughts](https://books.google.it/books?id=sahFH2CcpywC&pg=PA121), Birkhäuser (1997)

Comment: See also by [G.H. Hardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._H._Hardy) : [A mathematician's apology](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A%20Mathematician's%20Apology.pdf) (1940).

Comment: @Not_Here So do you find Vsauce cold and austere? Or loud and annoying?

Comment: My view of him is irrelevant, you said "you can only appreciate math to the degree that you've spent years learning to understand it" which is untrue. You attacking his demeanor which has nothing to do with your statement that people can't appreciate the beauty of mathematics without years of training is a pretty blatant non sequiter. At any rate, even if you find him loud and annoying, many of the professors who participate in the numberphile/sixty syombols/etc projects, such as Hannah Fry, James Grime, etc. are perfectly affable.

Comment: @Not_Here I prefer videos that start with the lecturer's head in the frame.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA good answer with the book shame that no-one has read it and can answer

Comment: @Not_Here "Mathematical beauty can be very accessible" the popular opinion is that it *isn't* -- which is why i seized upon the idea of its "austere" beauty (i'm no mathematical genius)

Comment: @Not_Here e.g. see this http://www.vislab.ucl.ac.uk/pdf/MathBeauty.pdf psychology peer reviewed article "Art and mathematics are, to most, at polar opposites; the former
has a more “sensible” source and is accessible to many while the
latter has a high cognitive, intellectual, source and is accessible to
few." people can appreciate the beauty of very complex atonal music with no training, the lack of a key, how its performance may superficially bring that out. i wouldn't take comments on youtube too seriously

Answer (score 5):

Belated and subjective, but I had an answer that didn't appear in the comments so I thought I'd mention it:

The beauty of mathematics is cold and austere because of how dreadfully, terrifyingly *simple* it is. It certainly doesn't look like it from the outside, I'm sure -- but having studied, you quickly realize that unlike any other field mathematics contains absolutely nothing but what is absolutely necessary -- indeed, it could be *defined* as "that which follows from a minimal set of assumptions."

Where beauty in other forms is, to paraphrase Millay, 'clothed' in trappings of culture or appeal or simply a richer narrative of many interweaving parts, the beauty of mathematics is 'bare'. There is something sublime in a proof -- most especially, those that start from incredibly obvious assumptions and yet prove that something not at all obvious must hold in incredible generality -- and yet by its very nature there is *nothing else*, nothing *but* that sublime-ness.

Thus is the beauty of mathematics 'sublimely pure,' 'cold and austere.'

Answer (score 0):

I hate that quote. Mathematics is a human creation, warm and kind, flawed and repairable, just like art (which was perfectly clear to the Eastern philosophers and poets, see Lu Chi'
s Wen Fu in the 3rd century). To turn mathematics into an untouchable statue means to put a weapon in the hands of tyrants to intimidate and deceive their subjects. A child who experiences an AHA moment during an experiment in math or geometry is much more of a follower of Archimedes than an academic flying on his Laputa carpet enveloped in a cloud of arrogance and stupidity.